# file upload user profile

Tags: custom-field, user-roles, user-registration, user-access, users

I am working on a medical reporting site in wordpress, where the requirement is that admin can upload a seperate .pdf file to different users' profile & only the profile owner can download it

Comment: ...Ok. Great. Did you have a question or are you expecting someone to do this for you? Or are you asking for plugin recommendations? Keeping in mind that's [off-topic here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a medical record, you probably so use a [transient download URL](https://mondaybynoon.com/protected-wordpress-downloads/) for the session when the profile is logged on, and destroy that URL when the users logs off, this ensures that the file is not accessible to others.

I used [WP Customer Area](https://wordpress.org/plugins/customer-area/) plugin on a CRM project and found it extremely useful for this kind of problem.  You can create a secure page for customer, and secure file attachments in the dashboard which only the profile can access.